# ArrayAdapter for Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

I am converting Activity to Fragment but I have an error on this line.
What should I use instead of

```
MainActivity.this.arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to judge what's wrong and what you are trying to achieve, as you have provided very little code.

If you moved arrayAdapter to fragment just as well then calling this in fragment should work:

```
this.arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
```

if arrayAdapter is in activity you can call this in fragment:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).applyFilter(charSequence);
```

And then in your activity:

```
public void applyFilter(CharSequence charSequence)
{
  this.arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
}
```

Also take a note that, it is not advisable to call activity directly from fragment. Instead take a look at this article:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html